# JQuery UI datepicker determine if Saturday clicked

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker and if someone selects a Saturday I want it to update a form select with different options - any idea how to do this?

I thought I could use the onSelect function, but all my attempts thus far do not work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

- awesome - that tells me they have selected Saturday, but then how do I change the form select values to represent that. Basically for all days during the week is a set value of options, but the options narrow if a Saturday...

Comment: Add what have you tried so far. also add your code.

Comment: Can you brief little more about what do you want to do if it is saturday?

Answer (score 3):

It is very simply Below is code to do that.

```
function doSomething() {
    var date1 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var day = date1.getDay();
    if (day == 6) {
        //this is saturday do you code here.
        alert("Saturday");
    }
}

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: doSomething
 });
```

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/v4327/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way.

```
$("#TxtStrtDate").datepicker({

    changeMonth: true,

    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = date.getUTCDay();
        if (day == '6') {
            alert('its a saturday');

        }

    }
});
```

The `getUTCDay()` method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date, according to universal time.

Note: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/v4327/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get that saturnday is selected. Run your code after selection is confirmed.

```
var date = $("#datepickerID").datepicker('getDate');
var dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();

alert(dayOfWeek);

if(dayOfWeek == "saturnday") {

 // Do the magic

}
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: It gets the selected day. Just need to add if the day is saturnday which is basic if clause

Comment: awesome - that tells me they have selected Saturday, but then how do I change the form select values to represent that. Basically for all days during the week is a set value of options, but the options narrow if a Saturday...

Comment: You cannot update the select in // Do the magic section? Or are you asking how to change select fields?

Answer (score 0):

Get current date from your datepicker then USE 
javascript date object:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Here is the function to check which day it is

```
var d = new Date("Your_DATE_FROM_UI_DATEPICKER");

if(d.getDay()==6){
 // Do your task
 }
```

For you if it is 6. Put if else condition for check it is 6 or not then do your stuff there